# Find Exact Match Record and String Contains column 1 row word

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 columns abc and bcd i want to compare abc data with bcd column exact match and sentence contain abc.

[image: I have 2 columns abc and bcd i want to compare abc data with bcd column exact match and sentence contain word]

Expected Result

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results, as tabular text (not images), as well as the query that you have tried so far.

Comment: @ maSTAShuFu I tried this `select abc,bcd from db where  abc=bcd;`and getting one row with exact match

Comment: Do you mean something like "select all rows, where the column bcd contains any of the values provided in column abc somewhere"?

Comment: @Kaii yes exactly

Comment: thats not easily possible, as you would need to dynamically create a query based on the current unique contents of all rows for column "abc". Like `SELECT * WHERE bcd LIKE '%patient%' OR bcd LIKE '%xyz%'  OR bcd LIKE '%xyz1%'`. In MySQL this is not possible easily. Also, if you really do this, it will perform _really badly_ with a growing dataset.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? what is your actual data, and what is your goal? I suspect that the database design could need some rework for the use case presented here...

Comment: @Kaii thanks but I don't want hardcoded the values because my data is about million

Comment: see my second question then. if you have a million or more rows, just forget about what you are trying to achieve because such a query will never execute quickly. Share a more detailed example or your data and tell us more about your use case (what you are actually trying to achieve, like, with real things) so we can help you.

Comment: I don't understand the example. Why is `'xyz' | 'i am patient data'` in the results? I thought you wanted a match between abc and bcd. There is no `'xyz'` in `'i am patient data'` or vice versa.

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to select all rows where there exists a row the abc of which matches the rows' bcd? Then use `EXISTS`.

```
select *
from mytable
where exists
(
  select null
  from mytable other
  where mytable.bcd like concat('%', other.abc, '%')
)
order by abc, bcd;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE table_name.abc like  CONCAT('%', table_name.bcd, '%');
```

This will return all records where string from `abc` column is contained in a string from `bcd` column.

Of course, replace `table_name` with your table name.

Comment: This will find exact match from two column

Comment: It shouldn't. Did you try to run it, what results did you get?